dropping a column with more than 60% missing values
as the title suggest i m working on a dataset and there are about 60% missing values of a certain column ,should i simply drop the column instead of imputing it ,the reason behind it is ,i am working on  crimes dataset ,as this is quite serious we cant not simply impute the values and it might let the world have wrong info about that weapon description or should i just replace the missing values with unknown .As this approach also seems fine to me .

You should check to see if the missing values are actually missing at random, or if they have a pattern among themselves. If they are missing at random, then if the feature is categorical you could try imputing all of the NA values with a string "na_value" or such; if the feature is numerical, then you could try multiple imputation (sklearn IterativeImputer in Python or MICE in R).
However, as the feature is missing 60% of its values, you could try dropping the feature, as you stated. Try building a model with the feature and without the feature to see if there is a difference.
